# Getting "NameError: name 'requests' is not defined" after already installing requests (using JuypterLab)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nameerror

I have already installed requests using `'pip install requests'` but I'm getting nothing back.

I'm following the example given in a basic [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5cSNSeBhjw) and keep getting this `error` on this `code`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.19044000000008&lon=-122.29563999999999#.Xq3cLZl7lPY')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html-parser')
print(soup)
```

and the `error`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-90e58007c1ee> in <module>
      1 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
----> 2 page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.19044000000008&lon=-122.29563999999999#.Xq3cLZl7lPY')
      3 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html-parser')
      4 print(soup)

NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
```

Comment: do you have an ```import requests``` statement at the top of your code? ```pip install requests``` installs the package on your machine, but you then need an import statement in your code.

Comment: the error is 'not defined' and not 'not found'. Are you sure you import requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you need to `import requests`. You can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.19044000000008&lon=-122.29563999999999#.Xq3cLZl7lPY')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Comment: This worked! I'm not very familiar with using libraries. Are there any good tutorials that would be useful to get more familiar with their use?